# How to create dsl

Tags: ruby, dsl

I want to make DSL construction for my class something like

```
class Car 
  brand :mercedes
end
```

What code I need to write?

Comment: You should look at the Docile Gem. https://github.com/ms-ati/docile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`brand` should be a method. It has to be defined somewhere. You have options: the very same class, parent class or mixed module. I like modules.

```
module MyDSL
  def brand name
    puts "Got brand #{name}"
  end
end

class Car 
  extend MyDSL

  brand :mercedes
end

# >> Got brand mercedes
```

While this answers your concrete question, I strongly recommend getting this book: [Metaprogramming Ruby](http://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby). Seems that you'll find many answers there.